# How to remove all li elements inside an ul except the first and the last elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` element. How can remove all the `<li>` elements inside it, except for the first and the last, using jQuery?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To remove from all ul-s on the page the li-s that are neither the first nor the last:

```
$('ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').remove();
```

Or using a specific id:

```
$('#yourul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').remove();
```

If you have a jQuery object with your ul in it:

```
$(yourul).find('li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').remove();
```

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried selecting all the list elements, and then removing the first and last ones from the list?

```
$('ul li').not('li:first, li:last').remove()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('ul li').not('li:first, li:last').remove();
```

This will remove all items from list **Except/Exclude** first and last element,

---

To remove all items from any list

```
$('#yourulid li').remove();  //remove all li items from list named/id #yourulid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using `slice`

```js
$("#removeAllButFirstAndLast").click(function() {
  $("#myUL").children().slice(1, -1).remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>

<div id="removeAllButFirstAndLast">click to remove all but first and last</div>
```