# jCarousel: Can you remove all items and rebind to a new collection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

[jCarousel documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Dynamic-Content-Loading) states the following:

> - By passing the callback function itemLoadCallback as configuration option, you are able to dynamically **create** (li) items for the content.
>     {...}
> - jCarousel contains a convenience method add() that can be passed the index of the item to **create** and the innerHTML string of the item to be created.

My Question:

> Is it possible to **remove** all items and rebind to a new collection?

BTW: I don't necessarily need a "convenience method" to do this. I'm very open to workarounds.
FYI: [This strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906432/removing-all-li-elements-inside-a-ul-except-first-and-last-elements-in-jquery/906446#906446) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this but you need to keep a reference to the carousel around and call `reset` on it.  This can be achieved by using the `initCallback` option you pass to the jcarousel function.

```
function carousel_callback( carousel, state) {
    // BWA-HA...I have the carousel now....FEEL THE POWER!

    // reset empties it out
    $('#reset-caro').click( function( evt ) {
        carousel.reset();
    });

    // here's how to call add
    $('#add-to').click( function( evt ) {
        // ..this just adds to the first spot..modify as needed
        carousel.add(0, "<li>O HAI!</li>");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel( {
        initCallback: carousel_callback
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
  <a id="reset-caro" href="#">reset</a>

  <a id="add-to" href="#">add</a>  

  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li>MOM</li>
    <li>DAD</li>
    <li>BROTHER</li>
    <li>SISTER</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! I have two remarks: 1. FF 3.5.2 and Chrome: When I click 'reset' the first time, the items disappear (good), but they leave behind white boxes (bad). Other than that, the code works flawlessly. // 2. IE8: Does not handle this code gracefully. My CPU spikes to 50%. [This may speak to a jCarousel weakness, rather than a logic bug.]

Comment: Yeah, I noticed both of those issues as well. Both are all on jCarousel.  reset left those boxes no matter what I tried.

Comment: Thanks, Seth. You were a big help.

Comment: It's probably a little late for this, but I ran into this problem today also. To fix the white boxes, there's a style in the skin.css called .jcarousel-item-placeholder. it has a background of "#fff". if you remove this line or set it to background:none, you won't see the white boxes.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above, please also specify the size of your new carousel.

```
carousel.size(x);
```

This should eliminate the white empty boxes in IE (as described above).

Thanks,
Nik