# How do I prepend items to a jCarousel carousel?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have a carousel using the jCarousel plugin.

I would like to dynamically add 5 new images to a carousel containing 10.

That is easy enough with the `carousel.add` method inside a `for` loop.

The only issue is, it adds these 5 new items to the **end** of the carousel list, where I would like to add them to the **beginning** of the carousel list!

I can't see that jCarousel supports this — and can't seem to figure out how to add items to the beginning of a carousel list without resetting the carousel altogether (I was hoping [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375171/jcarousel-can-you-remove-all-items-and-rebind-to-a-new-collection) wasn't the answer).

Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

If you put a negative integer in the add method it should prepend it.

Example: `carousel.add(-1,html);`

Answer (score -2):

You can edit its library jcarousel.min.js at line no. 16 column no. 5441 .
just replace before to after .

SOme line of code is here.

{e<=0?this.list.prepend(b):j.before(b);