# jCarousel - dynamically add items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

I want to add some new items to my jCarousel. My jCarouse looks like:

```
<div id="alertMessagePanelId" class="jcarousel alertMessagePanelStyle">
    <ul id="mycarousel">
        <li><p>Alert Message: 1</p></li>
        <li><p>Alert Message: 2</p></li>
        <li><p>Alert Message: 3</p></li>
        <li><p>Alert Message: 4</p></li>
        <li><p>Alert Message: 5</p></li>
        <li><p>Alert Message: 6</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to make a function to add some new element to DOM. The elements are added, but the jCarousel is not seeing it.

```
function addAlertMessage() {
var ul = document.getElementById("mycarousel");
var il = document.createElement("li");
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New Message"));
il.appendChild(p);
ul.appendChild(il);  }
```

This is a correct way to add new elements to the jCarousel?

Comment: [This post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375171/jcarousel-can-you-remove-all-items-and-rebind-to-a-new-collection)

Comment: I already tried this. The new element is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it is pretty simple. After you added new items, you just need to call

```
$('carousel-selector').jcarousel('reload', {});
```

Look this for more information: [jCarousel reload](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#reload)

Comment: It's not working. The elements are still not visible in jcarousel.