# Toggling the <LI> tags based on the count

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following code snippet and require to show only the first 2 `<LI>` and hide all the other `<LI>`. How can i acheive this? I basically need to toggle the show and hide on a button click using jquery.

Code Snippet:

```
<UL>
  <LI/>
  <LI/>
  <LI/>
  <LI/>
  <LI/>
</UL>
```

Comment: Here is the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906432/removing-all-li-elements-inside-a-ul-except-first-and-last-elements-in-jquery

Comment: @user47900 - That's not really the solution. That asks about removing the first and last items. This question asks about hiding everything except the first 2 items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to select elements above a specified index. As elements are 0-indexed, everything above index 1 is selected:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    $("li:gt(1)").toggle();
});
```

The [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method hides elements that are currently visible, and shows elements that are currently hidden. Therefore, clicking `#someButton` will repeatedly toggle the `li` elements at index > 1 between hidden and visible.

It's probably also worth mentioning that there is an [`:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) that allows you to perform precisely the opposite sort of selection.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? @dfsq - Thanks for adding a demo!

Comment: +1 for you solution (mine was the same, but you were the first) so sharing the demo

Comment: I did not know about the :gt selector nice answer.

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake... I accidently downvoted instead of upvoting

Comment: @Abhi - You should be able to remove the downvote in that case.

Comment: Ignorance.. how can i do that ? upvote again ? When i upvote it says your vote is locked :(

Comment: No, I think you can just click on the downvote button again to undo it... I'm not 100% sure though! If you can't, it doesn't matter, I just wanted to know if there was a reason for a downvote (completely misunderstood the question or something).

Comment: ohh yes ! it did the trick. Thanks ! It reminds me of a quote from steve jobs : "Simple can be harder than complex"

Comment: No problem :) And I like that quote.

Comment: Thanks James appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
  <ul>
    <li style='display:none'>first</li>
    <li style='display:none'>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>forth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
 </ul>
```

Then toggle on li elements:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).toggle(600);
});
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/w8DVE/)

Comment: @JamesAllardice has the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

James Allardice has a better answer. If you want the list items to be hidden before the list is rendered put this in your code somewhere

```
$('ul li:gt(1)').hide();
```